# Possible to split up a large excel file automatically?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to split up a large excel file automatically when it gets placed to a specific directory?  Is there a script that can run in the background that would accomplish this goal?

I would need this file split up by filtering the data within the excel workbook.

Comment: A script could be written to do this, though I'm not sure having a script running in the background constantly is a good design for this task.  Have you tried writing code to split up the file at all?  And what requirements do you have for splitting the file?

Comment: The only requirements are to filter on two of the available columns (each having a set of statuses that will be choosen).

Comment: I should also mention this file is created hourly and stored on a shared directory.

Comment: Why do you want it to run automatically when the file is put in a directory? Perhaps it makes more sense to hook into whatever program is creating the file.

Comment: That's one option I have.  I'm exploring my options.  SQL is creating the excel file.  I would prefer not to have SQL create multiple files, but it is still an option.

Comment: For your second question, a working-around solution is "Task Scheduler". This is not the best practices, but you can code a `workbook_open sub` so the task scheduler look for it every sort of time.

Comment: Having SQL create multiple files seems like the simpler solution.  It is better to create the data you want from the start than to create something that needs post-processing. If you do decide on a script to split the file, perhaps you could have the same procedure that creates the file also call your script.  That way you don't have to have something running in the background.

Comment: That makes sense dan1111.  I will explore that option. BrOSs I'm not too familiar using Task Scheduler but I'm sure I can figure it out.  This could be a good option as well.

Comment: I really recommend you alter your SQL export function to split the file. Is it a CSV file or a XLS file? How is it being generated BY SSIS, BCP, SQLCMD, OPENQUERY?

Comment: It is a XLS file.  The file is being generated through SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

Using **C#** (or any **.Net** language) you can access the **FileSystemWatcher** component that will notify of any change in the directory.

Then you can split your file using any Excel interop API, like the standard one provided by PIAs (but you'll need Excel installed on the server running your deamon) or a file-only API like **NPOI** (.Net port of **Apache POI**) : http://npoi.codeplex.com/.